# Snowflake ALTER SQL is throwing an error when adding column with DEFAULT value along with IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, default, alter, not-exists

I am trying to run an `ALTER` query in Snowflake to add a column `TEST_COL`, if it does not exists already in the table `TEST_SALES`.

I would like to set a `DEFAULT` value of 'N' for the column as well.

This is the query I used:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_SALES
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS TEST_COL VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N';
```

On rerunning the same query, it throws this error:

> SQL Error [2028] [42601]: SQL compilation error: ambiguous column name 'TEST_COL'

Is there a solution?

Please note that it allows me to rerun any number of times, if I do not set the default value

Query used is:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_SALES
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS TEST_COL VARCHAR(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DEFAULT` is not allowed with `IF NOT EXISTS` when adding a column :

From [Docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table#table-column-actions-tablecolumnaction) :

> You cannot specify IF NOT EXISTS if you are also specifying any of the
> following for the new column:
>
> DEFAULT, AUTOINCREMENT, or IDENTITY
>
> UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, or FOREIGN KEY

Comment: Thanks for this information

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `IF NOT EXISTS` can be combined with `DEFAULT` (but it is ignored - based on observations v7.41.0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_SALES(i INT) AS SELECT 1;

ALTER TABLE TEST_SALES
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS TEST_COL VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N';
-- Statement executed successfully.

SELECT * FROM TEST_SALES;
-- I    TEST_COL
-- 1    N
```

Second run:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_SALES
ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS TEST_COL VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N';
-- ambiguous column name 'TEST_COL'
```

---

Workaround using Snowflake Script Block:

```
BEGIN
  IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
             WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'TEST_COL'
               AND TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_SALES' 
               AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC')) THEN
        ALTER TABLE TEST_SALES ADD COLUMN TEST_COL VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N';
   END IF;
END;

SELECT * FROM TEST_SALES;
```

Comment: Yes, it seems DEFAULT is not allowed while using IF NOT EXISTS. Thanks for the workaround